# jQuery slideshow ... how to add text from alt tag?

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I have been playing around with this slideshow:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/02/26/full-width-image-slider/

What I would like to have is the text from the current image ALT tag to show just below the image in the center .... is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is .attr() property in Jquery. you will get clear usage of this property in this link [This is official Jquery page](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)